# A C program process is waited by some OS routine?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, exit, zombie-process

Well, I'm learning about processes using the C language, and I have seen that when you call the exit function a process is terminated and without waiting for it, it will become a zombie process. My question is, if the first process created when executing the program is a process itself, is there a 0S routine that wait for it after an exit() call, avoiding that it becomes a zombie process? I'm curious about it.

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process ? It's pretty clear IMO

Comment: "...if the first process created when executing the program is a process itself..." To me this is unclear. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

For Unix systems at least (and I expect Windows is similar), when the system boots, it creates one special first process. Every process after that is created by some existing process.

When you log into a windowed desktop interface, there is some desktop manager process (that has been created by the first process or one of its descendants) managing windows. When you start a program by clicking on it, that desktop manager or one of its children (maybe some file manager software) creates a process to run the program. When you start a program by executing a command in a terminal window, there is a command line shell process that is interpreting the things you type, and it creates a process to run the program.

So, in all cases, your user program has a parent process, either a command-line shell or some desktop software.

Answer (score 0):

If a child process creates another child (even as the first instruction) then the parent also has to wait for it or it becomes a zombie.

Basically processes always become zombie until they are removed from the process table, the OS (via the process init) will handle and wait() for orphans (zombies without parents), it does that periodically so normally you won't have orphans running for very long.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the top most (parent) process is **init**. This is the only process, which has no parent. Any other process (without any exception) do have a parent and hence is a child of another process.

**See:**

- [init](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/init.1.html)
- Section **NOTES** on [wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html#NOTES)

  > A child that terminates, but has not been waited for becomes a
  > "zombie".  The kernel maintains a minimal set of information
  > about the zombie process (PID, termination status, resource usage
  > information) in order to allow the parent to later perform a wait
  > to obtain information about the child.  As long as a zombie is
  > not removed from the system via a wait, it will consume a slot in
  > the kernel process table, and if this table fills, it will not be
  > possible to create further processes.  If a parent process
  > terminates, then its "zombie" children (if any) are adopted by
  > init(1), ... init(1) automatically performs a wait to remove the
  > zombies.